# Android/Java AI agent framework/middleware

Tags: java, android, ai

I am looking for an AI agent framework to use as a starting point in an Android game I have to create for a university research project. It has been suggested to me to use [JADE](http://jade.tilab.com), but, as far as I can tell, it's not a suitable framework for games (at least for my game idea) because it runs in a split-execution mode, and it needs an always-active network connection to a main host.

What I want is just a little something to give me a headstart. I am willing to adjust the game's features to the framework because it's more of a mockup game, and the purpose is to compare the performance of a couple of agents in the game world. The game will be very simplistic, with a minimal UI that displays various stats about the characters in the game (so no graphics, no pathfinding).

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this will be useful? http://repast.sourceforge.net/repast_simphony.html

Comment: Have you made any progress in your project, I'm interested to learn about it.

Comment: No, I've been much too busy with other things. If I ever manage to make any progress, I'll add an update with my experiences, so wish me luck (and spare time) :).

Answer (score 2):

I may be dating myself here a bit but I've had the best results with Jade for multi-agent systems.

http://jade.tilab.com/

They also seem to be focusing on Android in recent years. There is quite a bit on documentation including a book that had be jumpstarted in just a few hours: [Deploying multi-agent systems with JADE](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=ZLBQAAAAMAAJ)

One last thought: though FIPA is now replaced by IEEE I always gravitate toward standards compliant frameworks, like Jade, where possible. This gives at least some measure of confidence that the framework will continue to be useful into the future.

Good luck with your project.

Comment: Hi Kelly, and welcome to GDSE! It's a good idea to also mention the name of a book you're linking to, in case the link goes dead. I've inlined your link.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [JaCa-Android](http://jaca-android.sourceforge.net/) myself for a university project, though it's not for a game. After researching a plethora of mobile agent frameworks, it appears to be the most suitable for an Android device, since it integrates very smoothly and can run a middleware app to access all the Android system features (like notifications and sensors). The Jason language is an extension of AgentSpeak which itself is very Prolog-like, and the agents can easily call methods of Java objects in the environment.

No doubt this is too late to answer your question, but for future reference, I've had good experiences with it so far.

Comment: Thank you. No it's not too late. I've postponed the project, being too busy with my job. I'll check it out and maybe I'll choose this.